# Why is ("00" == "0".repeat(2)) false?

Tags: java

Isn't it supposed to be true, since "00" is equal to "00"?

I also tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(("00" == repeat("0",2)));
    }
    public static String repeat(String str, int n) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            output += str;
        }
        return output;
```

But it still prints false.

Comment: You should use .equals in this situation. == compares object identity.

Comment: In Java, `==` checks for object identity (is it the same object), not if two objects have the same value. You need to use `"00".equals(repeat("0",2))`, see the duplicate.